# If someone types 'api/movies/1' , I want to display Citizen Kane object in json format. Can you see my mistake? My result: Cannot GET /api/movies/1

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to display individual movie objects from array when someone types, for example , localhost:5050/api/movies/1, then I would display Citizen Kane. I can display the array and the welcome message but I keep getting the following message when I try with the id 'Cannot GET /api/movies/1'. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

```
enter code here
```

const express = require("express");

```
const app = express();

const port = 5050;

 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.send("Welcome to my favourite movie list");
});

 app.get("/api/movies/", function (request, response) {
 response.status(200).json(movies);
});

app.get("api/movies/:id", function (request, response) {
response.send("movies " + req.params.id);
});

const movies = [
{
id: 1,
title: "Citizen Kane",
director: "Orson Wells",
year: "1941",
colors: false,
duration: 120,
},
{
id: 2,
title: "The Godfather",
director: "Francis Ford Coppola",
year: "1972",
colors: true,
duration: 180,
},
{
id: 3,
title: "Pulp Fiction",
director: "Quentin Tarantino",
year: "1994",
color: true,
duration: 180,
},
];

app.listen(port, (err) => {
if (err) {
console.error("Something bad happened");
} else {
console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
}
});
```

Comment: For starters, change this `app.get("api/movies/:id", ...)` to this `app.get("/api/movies/:id", ...)`  There are no relative URL paths on your server.  Everything starts with `/`.  If the user types a relative path, the browser will turn it into an absolute path before sending to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jfriend00 points out, the URL of your GET request should begin with a forward slash. Next you will want to change:

```
response.send("movies " + req.params.id);
```

to something like...

```
response.status(200).json({"movie": movies[req.params.id] })
```

I also see that in some places you use `req` and `res` but in other places you use `request` and `response`. You might want to be consistent in order to avoid mistakes.